# Real, symmetric matrices $A, B \ge 0$ with $A$ positive definite, must we have $\lVert (A +B)^{-1}B \rVert_{\text{op}} \le 1$?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

If $A$ is positive definite and $B$ is positive semi definite, both symmetric real matrices, with $A - B$ positive semi-definite, must we have $\lVert (A+B)^{-1}B \rVert \le 1$ in the operator norm?

I think it holds that the max eigenvalue is smaller than 1, but not sure about the operator norm: that is $$A +B \ge B \implies I \ge (A+B)^{-1/2}B(A+B)^{-1/2}$$ so all eigenvalues of $(A+B)^{-1}B$ are smaller than 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(A+B)^{-1} B$ has eigenvalues $< 1$, but it isn't symmetric so its norm could be greater than $1$.
Try e.g.
$$ A = \pmatrix{1 & -1\cr -1 & 1\cr},\ B = \pmatrix{1/2 & -1/2\cr
-1/2 & 1},\ u = \pmatrix{0\cr 1\cr} $$

$$ (A+B)^{-1} B u = \pmatrix{2/3\cr 1\cr}$$
so $\|(A+B)^{-1} B u\| > \|u\|$ and $\|(A+B)^{-1} B\| > 1$.

This $A$ is positive semidefinite rather than positive definite, but add a small multiple of $I$ to make it positive definite and the counterexample will still work.